# Error while using cv.glmnet in R for multinomial

Tags: r, glmnet

While trying to use `cv.glmnet` to perform cross validation for my data I got the error

```
Error in apply(nz, 1, median) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

In the line below, `y` is a 3 level variable (I used `as.factor()` on the original variable). The predictor `x` is made up of one continuous variable(mage) and some factor variables (again used `as.factor()` on the categorical variables). As suggested by another post online, my code to collect all the predictors together was:

```
xfactors <- model.matrix(ANYHEART ~ mrace+frace+sex+smoke+alcohol+bmi+dbt+ben+tol+
                                    xyl+car+chl+met+per+tca+tce+sto+chlor+arom)[,-1]
x <- as.matrix(data.frame(mage, xfactors))
y <- as.factor(ANYHEART)
fit = glmnet(x, y, family="multinomial", type.multinomial="grouped")
```

Followed by cross-validation using:

```
cvfit <- cv.glmnet(x, y, family="multinomial", type.multinomial="grouped")
```

I was wondering if anyone has faced this problem before and what could be the possible causes.

Comment: There is some discussion here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21315/error-when-running-glmnet-in-multinomial Supposedly it was fixed in glmnet 1.7.3 but it is still being reported. 
I am seeing this error with real-world data using R 3.2.1 on Windows and glmnet 2.0-2. The training data has 449 observations of 229 predictors. The response variable has 9 levels. Any suggestions on how to proceed would be welcome.